# Why can users delete each others files in this case

Tags: linux, permissions, files

I have two users : bob and sally, who resepctively own two files : bob100 and sally100:

```
> ls -altrh /path/to/dir : 

-rw-r--r--. 1 bob   test    0 Jan  7 12:59 bob100
-rw-r--r--. 1 sally test    0 Jan  7 13:06 sally100
drwxrwxrwx. 8 root  root 4.1K Jan  7 13:06 .
```

However, BOB can delete files in SALLY's account:

```
> runuser -l bob -c 'rm -f /path/to/dir/sally100'
```

Why is it that bob is allowed to delete a file which clearly only sally has write permissions on?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because group/others have write permissions on a parent directory. File deletion is actually unlinking it from the directory. The directory is being modified, not the file.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to afford some protection to files in a shared directory, set the `sticky` bit on the directory (i.e. `chmod +t mydir`).  When the `sticky` bit is set for a directory, only 'root' or the owner of a file may unlink (delete) it.  Usually, this bit is on for `/tmp` and `/var/tmp`.